# Extract Java Cluster Creation functionality for a Java Web App

Tags: java, spring, cluster-computing, discovery

Our spring based webapp is deployed to Tomcat AppServer. We have Multiple Tomcat Nodes behind a Load Balancer. If we want to discover all the AppServer Nodes in the Cluster, which clustering library can be used ? [Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery) has TcpIp Multicast based and other cluster discovery mechanisms and Hazelcast has similar discovery mechanisms.

If our cluster size is roughly at 10 nodes, it appears that TcpIp Multicast based discovery would be a right strategy. Is that assumption right ?

Did anyone extract just the Cluster discovery feature from ignite ? If not, how do I go about extracting just the Cluster creating code and peer to group/peer messaging feature from Ignite (or any similar library/framework) ?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'll rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK JBoss clustering functions used to run on top of [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/).
You already mentioned Hazelcast...

Comment: What I am looking for is just the Cluster creation and communication part of Ignite and Hazelcast. I don't want the remaining 95% of their feature set.

Comment: Will look to JGroups.